# Android load image from url in every 30 sec

Tags: android, android-activity

I found difficulty to load image from url in every 30 seconds in android imageview,this effect performance issue.I am no able to perform any other button click action on that android-activity because of continues image loading.How can I improve performance?.Is there is a way to perform this in background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).  Perform your image loading from URL in `doInBackground` and then update your ImageView in `onPostExecute`.

Comment: I have set timer to invoked in 30 seconds for check server for updated images.For this I invoke AsyncTask inside timer and fetch url data part on doInBackground and then update  ImageView inside onPostExecute. But problem I found is as this timer is invoking every 30 seconds I am not able to perform button click on this page.Is there is a way to do this?